# AH01630: client denied by server configuration

Tags: server, client, apache2

I am assuming that I have tried all possible solutions mentioned here, but I am still unable to fix the problem.

The problem is with the httpd.conf and .htaccess files.

If I run `tail -f access.log` I get :

> AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /opt/rpkica/share/rpki/wsgi/rpki.wsgi

This is the configuration I'm using :

```
<Directory /opt/rpkica/share/rpki/wsgi>

    Order allow,deny
    AllowOverride All
    Allow from All
    #Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to find .htaccess file recursively from "document root" for that virtual host. .htacces have a precedence over main configuration so check if you have deny configuration in any .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to check httpd.conf file

```
<Directory /path/to/directory>
    Options FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride none
    Require all granted
  </Directory>
```

If you may get an error on ***XAMPP server***, open **httpd-xampp.conf** file under the path /opt/lampp/etc/extra

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
 #       Require local
        ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>
```

Just command the  "Require local" then restart your lampp service

```
# /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```